dSYM file missing on Xcode 15 archive
In Xcode 14, when I archived my project, it generated a .dSYM file within the .xcarchive.
Since upgrading to Xcode 15, this no longer get generated. Why?
(I do not believe I changed any project settings between the two versions.)
Did something change in how Apple symbolicates crash reports? I've noticed that even though the .dSYM isn't being generated locally, when there's been a crash report via TestFlight, it is fully symbolicated. So... does it even matter?
Within my build settings I have:

Debug Information Format: DWARF with dSYM File (DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT=dwarf-with-dsym)
Strip Debug Symbols During Copy: Yes (COPY_PHASE_STRIP=YES)
Strip Linked Product: Yes (STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT=YES)
Strip Style: All Symbols (STRIP_STYLE=all)
Generate Debug Symbols: Yes (GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=YES)

Within my scheme I have:

Archive Build Configuration: Release

